# Privoxy rule to block Facebook spying

Tags: malware, privoxy

Recently, my server's Privoxy rules to block Facebook's spying have failed. **How can I block current Facebook spying links?**

Since soon after [the inception of Facebook's so-called “Open Graph” cross-site tracking widgets](http://www.demystifyingusability.com/2010/05/facebooks-privacy-fail-lessons-for-designing-privacy-in-social-networks.html) (those “Like” bugs on numerous websites), I blocked them by using this rule (in `user.action`) on our site's Privoxy server:

```
{ +block-as-image{People-tracking button.} }
.facebook.com/(plugins|widgets)/(like|fan|activity).*
```

That worked fine; the spying bugs no longer appeared on any web page.

Today I noticed that they're all making it past that filter [**edit: no, they're not**].

**SOLUTION**: The proxy was being silently ignored, though this was not obvious in the client. The above rule continues to work fine.

Comment: What are like bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this out; the proxy was being silently ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I found this wasn't blocking a facebook window for me so I added "activity" in there with like and fan (ie, (like|fan) becomes (like|fan|activity). Not sure exactly what the activity bit is but hiding that php page made the Facebook annoyance and constant page reloads that occur after implementing this: http://bmearns.net/wwk/view/Privoxy

FWIW to anyone.

Comment: +1 for the update to the regex. I've incorporated that into the question for future reference.